# Collide_Rect not detecting

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Is there some reason why my pieces are detecting a collision in the play function?

When I print out the location of the pieces, they say that they are in the correct place, but the collision is not picking up on it for some reason.

```
import pygame
import os
import random

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 512)
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

font = pygame.font.SysFont("times", 20)

black = (0,0,0)

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color(color))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("coin.jpg")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (20,20))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

###############################################################################
#intializeing class

class PygameGame(object):
    def init(self): 
        self.mode = 'home'
        self.prevMode = 'home'
        self.homeFunctions = {'keyPressed':self.homeKeyPressed,
                            'keyReleased':self.homeKeyReleased,
                            'mousePressed':self.homeMousePressed,
                            'mousePosition':self.homeMousePosition,
                            'redrawAll':self.homeRedrawAll,
                            'timerFired':self.homeTimerFired
                            }
        self.pausedFunctions = {'keyPressed':self.pausedKeyPressed,
                            'keyReleased':self.pausedKeyReleased,
                            'mousePressed':self.pausedMousePressed,
                            'mousePosition':self.pausedMousePosition,
                            'redrawAll':self.pausedRedrawAll,
                            'timerFired':self.pausedTimerFired
                            }
        self.playFunctions = {'keyPressed':self.playKeyPressed,
                            'keyReleased':self.playKeyReleased,
                            'mousePressed':self.playMousePressed,
                            'mousePosition':self.playMousePosition,
                            'mouseMotion': self.playMouseMotion,
                            'redrawAll':self.playRedrawAll,
                            'timerFired':self.playTimerFired
                            }
        self.instructionFunctions = {'keyPressed':self.instructKeyPressed,
                                    'keyReleased':self.instructKeyReleased,
                                    'mousePressed':self.instructMousePressed,
                                    'mousePosition':self.instructMousePosition,
                                    'redrawAll':self.instructRedrawAll,
                                    'timerFired':self.instructTimerFired
                                    }

        self.textSize = 20

        self.players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.player = Player("coin.jpg")
        self.wallOne = Wall('black', self.width//4, self.height//4, 10, 20)

        self.walls.add(self.wallOne)
        self.players.add(self.player)
        self.allSprites.add(self.wallOne, self.player)


        self.collide = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.wallOne, self.player)

##############################################################################
## home

    def homeMousePressed(self, x, y):
        self.mode = 'play'

    def homeMousePosition(self, x, y):
        pass

    def homeKeyPressed(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def homeKeyReleased(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def homeTimerFired(self, dt):
        pass

    def homeRedrawAll(self, screen):
        #title
        text = "Omega"
        title = font.render(text, False, (0,0,0))
        centered = title.get_rect(center=(self.width//2, self.height//2)) 
        screen.blit(title, (centered))
        #how to play
        text = "click to play"
        title = font.render(text, False, (255,0,0))
        centered = title.get_rect(center=(self.width//2, self.height//2+2*self.textSize)) 
        screen.blit(title, (centered))


###############################################################################      
#play

    def playMousePressed(self, x, y):
        pass

    def playMouseMotion(self, x, y):
        pass

    def playMousePosition(self, x, y):
        pass

    def playKeyPressed(self, keyCode):
        print(self.collide)
        print("playerY= ", self.player.rect.y)
        print("playerX= ", self.player.rect.x)
        print("WallX,Y= ", self.width//4, self.height//4)
        print("********************************")
        if self.collide:
            print("made it")
        else:
            if keyCode == pygame.K_s:
                self.player.rect.y += 5
            if keyCode == pygame.K_w:
                self.player.rect.y -= 5
            if keyCode == pygame.K_a:
                self.player.rect.x -= 5
            if keyCode == pygame.K_d:
                self.player.rect.x += 5

    def playKeyReleased(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def playTimerFired(self, dt):
        pass

    def playRedrawAll(self, screen):
        self.allSprites.draw(screen)
        self.allSprites.update() 

##############################################################################
#paused 

    def pausedMousePressed(self, x, y):
        pass

    def pausedMousePosition(self, x, y):
        pass

    def pausedKeyPressed(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def pausedKeyReleased(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def pausedTimerFired(self, dt):
        pass

    def pausedRedrawAll(self, screen):
        pass


###############################################################################
#Instructions

    def instructMousePressed(self, x, y):
        pass

    def instructMousePosition(self, x, y):
        pass

    def instructKeyPressed(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def instructKeyReleased(self, keyCode):
        pass

    def instructTimerFired(self, dt):
        pass

    def instructRedrawAll(self, screen):
        pass        


################################################################################
#big stuff below

    def isKeyPressed(self, key):
        ''' return whether a specific key is being held '''
        return self._keys.get(key, False)

    def __init__(self, width=900, height=500, fps=100, title="112 Pygame Game"):
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.fps = fps
        self.title = title
        self.bgColor = (255, 255, 255)
        pygame.init()

    def doLoop(self,func,time,screen):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                func['mousePressed'](*(event.pos))

            elif (event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and
                    event.buttons == (0, 0, 0)):
                func['mousePosition'](*(event.pos))

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._keys[event.key] = True
                func['keyPressed'](event.key)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._keys[event.key] = False
                func['keyReleased'](event.key)

            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.playing = False
        func['timerFired'](time)
        func['redrawAll'](screen)

##################################################################
    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        # set the title of the window
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)

        # stores all the keys currently being held down
        self._keys = dict()

        # call game-specific initialization
        self.init()
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            screen.fill(self.bgColor)
            time = clock.tick(self.fps)
            # the 'name' functions are dictionaries that hold the key, mouse and draw func for a mode
            if self.mode == 'home':
                self.doLoop(self.homeFunctions,time,screen)
            elif self.mode == 'paused':
                self.doLoop(self.pausedFunctions,time,screen)
            elif self.mode == 'play':
                self.doLoop(self.playFunctions,time,screen)
            elif self.mode == 'instructions':
                self.doLoop(self.instructionFunctions,time,screen)
            pygame.display.update()

        pygame.quit()

def main():
    game = PygameGame()
    game.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never update `self.collide` in your while loop, so the value is always the same as in your `init` method where you assign it the first time. Try to do this every frame: `self.collide = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.wallOne, self.player)`.